# how I fix unicode error in Python Dexterity Type?

Tags: python, zope, dexterity, plone-4.x

I created one Dexterity Type using python, and the code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from plone.app.textfield import RichText
from plone.autoform import directives
from plone.namedfile import field as namedfile
from plone.supermodel.directives import fieldset
from plone.supermodel import model
from z3c.form.browser.radio import RadioFieldWidget
from zope import schema
from zope.schema.vocabulary import SimpleVocabulary
from zope.schema.vocabulary import SimpleTerm
from DateTime import DateTime

from projetime.ged import MessageFactory as _

TipoDeDocumentoVocabulary = SimpleVocabulary(
    [SimpleTerm(value=u'processo', title=_(u'Processos')),
     SimpleTerm(value=u'contratos', title=_(u'Contratos')),
     SimpleTerm(value=u'outros', title=_(u'Outros'))]
)

TipoDeUploadVocabulary = SimpleVocabulary(
    [SimpleTerm(value=u'sim', title=_(u'Sim')),
     SimpleTerm(value=u'nao', title=_(u'Não'))]
)

agora = DateTime()

class IDigitalFile(model.Schema):
    """Dexterity-Schema
    """

    directives.widget(TipoDeDocumento=RadioFieldWidget)
    TipoDeDocumento = schema.Choice(
        title=_(u"Tipo de Documento"),
        vocabulary=TipoDeDocumentoVocabulary,
        required=True
    )

    titulo = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Título"),
        required=True
    )

    codDoDocumento = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Cód. do Documento"),
        required=False
    )

    CpfCnpj = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"CPF/CNPJ"),
        required=False
    )

    Assunto = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Assunto"),
        required=True
        )

    Tipo = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Tipo"),
        required=False
    )

    Descricao = schema.Text(
        title=_(u"Descrição"),
        required=True
    )

    fieldset('File', fields['Arquivo'] )
    Arquivo = namedfile.NamedBlobFile(
        title=_(u"Arquivo Digitalizado"),
        required=True
    )

    directives.omitted(['Automatico', 'uploded_at'])
    directives.read_permission(Automatico="cmf.ManagePortal")
    directives.write_permission(Automatico="cmf.ManagePortal")
    directives.widget(Automatico=RadioFieldWidget)
    Automatico = schema.Bool(
        Title=_(u"Upload via Script?"),
        vocabulary=TipoDeUploadVocabulary,
        required=True,
        default=u"Não"
    )

    directives.read_permission(uploded_at="cmf.ManagePortal")
    directives.write_permission(uploded_at="cmf.ManagePortal")
    uploded_at = schema.Datetime(
        title=_(u"Data de Upload"),
        required=True,
        default=agora
    )
```

And the error is:

`WrongType: (<zope.i18nmessageid.message.MessageFactory object at 0x7f118f168890>, <type 'unicode'>, 'title')`

I Set up in fist line:

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

But the error persists.

Comment: This error message is too short. Do you have a stack trace? And are you using Python 2? A blind guess is that the i18n system is feeding your code with "str" strings while it expects "unicode" strings.

Comment: Plone 4.3.10 (4313), Python 2.7.12, Zope 2.13.24. I found something like in this url https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/386

Comment: I don't know what `projetime.ged.MessageFactory` is but you're importing it as `_`. If it is actually the same object as `ploneconf.site.MessageFactory` you're indeed having the same issue as in the bug report. If that's true, then try replacing that import with `from ploneconf.site import _`. I'm afraid I won't be able to help you out much!

Comment: You're right, is the same problem, I using this training to drive my product. I did the same and works. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions is change the line 13:

`from projetime.ged import MessageFactory as _`

to:

`from projetime.ged import _`

Like see here https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/386